# Overriding super method in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, abstract-class

I'm trying to overload/override a class method in TypeScript, where the superior method takes zero arguments and the subordinate method takes one.

My TypeScript code is similar to the following:

```
class Super {
  create(): void {}
}

class Sub extends Super {
  create(arg: object): void {}
}

const sub = new Sub();
sub.create({});
```

This code produces the following error:

```
Property 'create' in type 'Sub' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Super'.
  Type '(arg: object) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'. ts(2416)
```

Why doesn't this work? It it because the transpiled JavaScript output simply isn't capable of making an inheritance distinction between these two classes? How would I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, the type of a subclass must be assignable to the type of its parent class. This allows polymorphism to work:

```
let sub: Sub = new Sub();
// polymorphism: we can treat a Sub as a Super
let parent: Super = sub;
```

However, your code is not valid because in the situation above, we would be allowed to call `parent.create()` with no arguments; however, the code that actually runs is `Sub.create` which **requires** by contract that `arg` is present.

In summary: all members of the child's type must be assignable to the corresponding members of the parent's type. `(arg: any) => void` is not assignable to `() => void`.

Answer (score -2):

```
// index.ts

class Super {
    create(): void {}
}

class Sub extends Super {
    create(arg?: any): void {}
}

let sub = new Sub();
sub.create(1);
```